# Very simple PHP code crashes Apache

Tags: php, apache

I'm using Wampserver on Windows XP and Apache 2.2.21.

**This code crashes when executed:**

```
<?php

class Tax {
    public static function load($id)
    {
        echo $id;
    }
}

$tax = Tax::load(1);

?>
```

**This code DOES NOT crash when executed:**

```
<?php

class Tax {
    public static function load($id)
    {
        echo $id;
    }
}

$tax = Tax::load(10);

?>
```

Made simple, if I pass a single digit number to the function **load**, Apache crashes. However if I change the function name for anything else than **load**, it works fine. Also, I'm aware the function does not return anything, but it should still compile at the very least.

**This code works too:**

```
Tax::load(5);
```

I am kind of lost right now as I have no clue why this code would cause a crash. Help me please.

**EDIT**

I'm using PHP 5.3.10

There are no errors in the Apache error logs

Changing the variable name $tax for anything else (e.g. $a) works. I'm even more confused.

I know apache crashes because I get a windows error saying so. The Apache server restart automatically and is back up a minute or so after it crashes.

Comment: Sort of off-top, but php is not a compiled language, rather an interpreted language

Comment: why are you using `echo`? You should be using `return`. Also, do you have anything in the Apache/PHP log?

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of "crashes"? Do you receive any error?

Comment: `I'm aware the function does not return anything` He is aware of that. Catfish, that's not relevant, he probably meant "parse ok".

Comment: Works on my machine ok...

Comment: How do you know apache crashes?

Comment: P.s. Tell everyone witch version of PHP you're running...

Comment: @Catfish incorrect. PHP **does** go through a compilation process, and the resulting opcodes are run through a VM. You've probably heard of opcode caches, these store the compiled code for re-use, so the burden of compilation does not have to be repeated. [There's also little clues like this](http://php.net/halt_compiler)

Comment: possible 'load' is reserved or smth =)

Comment: Load isn't reserved. I'm using the exact same pattern in 4 other classes.

Comment: @user2012040 i tried your code and it doesnt crash. The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

If Apache is really crashing then you should look through the following file to see what happened:

```
[WAMP directory]/apache/logs/error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of $tax (the variable).

Answer (score 0):

just because it echos and is not return shouldn't crash apache.